# Searching the better solution for an sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
| col1 (varchar) | col2(varchar) | col3(varchar) | col4(bool) | col5(bool) | col6(bool) | col7(bool) |
|----------------|---------------|---------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| a              | a             | a             | true       | true       | false      | false      |
| b              | b             | b             | true       | true       | true       | true       |
| c              | c             | c             | false      | false      | true       | false      |
```

The columns 4 5 6 and 7 refers to types (type1,type2,type3,type4)

so if col4 is true  I have to assigne type1 to the tuple(col1,col2,col3) but one tuple can have multiple types so using the table above the result will be like this

```
| col1 (varchar) | col2(varchar) | col3(varchar) | type    |
|----------------|---------------|---------------|---------|
| a              | a             | a             | "type1" |
| a              | a             | a             | "type2" |
| b              | b             | b             | "type1" |
| b              | b             | b             | "type2" |
| b              | b             | b             | "type3" |
| b              | b             | b             | "type4" |
| c              | c             | c             | "type3" |
```

I can do it with 4 queries and using **CASE WHEN**

```
select col1,col2,col3, CASE col4 WHEN true THEN "type1" END from ... where ...;

select col1,col2,col3, CASE col5 WHEN true THEN "type2" END from ... where ...;

select col1,col2,col3, CASE col6 WHEN true THEN "type3" END from ... where ...;

select col1,col2,col3, CASE col7 WHEN true THEN "type4" END from ... where ...;
```

and concatenate the result in one table, but it is an expensive solution(I have to write all the queries).

> Is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array from the boolean columns and unnest it skipping nulls:

```
select col1, col2, col3, type
from (
    select 
        col1, col2, col3, unnest(array[
            case when col4 then 'type1' end,
            case when col5 then 'type2' end,
            case when col6 then 'type3' end,
            case when col7 then 'type4' end]) as type
    from my_table
    ) s
where type is not null;

 col1 | col2 | col3 | type  
------+------+------+-------
 a    | a    | a    | type1
 a    | a    | a    | type2
 b    | b    | b    | type1
 b    | b    | b    | type2
 b    | b    | b    | type3
 b    | b    | b    | type4
 c    | c    | c    | type3
(7 rows)
```

See online demo in [SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/69af6/4)

A solution without arrays:

```
select *
from (
    select col1, col2, col3, case when col4 then 'type1' end as type from my_table
    union all
    select col1, col2, col3, case when col5 then 'type2' end as type from my_table
    union all
    select col1, col2, col3, case when col6 then 'type3' end as type from my_table
    union all
    select col1, col2, col3, case when col7 then 'type4' end as type from my_table
    ) s
where type is not null
order by col1, col2, col3, type
```

Comment: Your solution is working perfectly, do you have any idea how to convert it to jpql

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one `case` expressions:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
       (CASE WHEN col4 THEN 'type1' 
             WHEN col5 THEN 'type2' 
             WHEN col6 THEN 'type3' 
             WHEN col7 THEN 'type4' 
        END) as type
from ...
where ...;
```

Note the use of single quotes.  These are the standard string delimiter in SQL.

Comment: @Gordon It doesn't work syntax error near "col5" shoud i add case near every col

Comment: @M.A.Bell no, it was a mistype, lack of coffee I guess, use `Case when col4 then 'type1' when col5 then 'type2' ... when col7 then 'type4' end as 'type'` ... but seems it won't be enough, as this case will give you back 3 rows as result instead of 7 wanted rows, think you will have to do `unpivot`